# android: Reload activity or refresh the view on spinner item selected,

Tags: android, android-activity, spinner

I have an activity in which I have added a spinner, depending on the value selected of spinner I have to update the whole view ***immidietly***,

this operation includes changing the locale (use of resource) and changing the background color(use of some local private variables).

I have tried `onItemSelected` and tried to reload same activity by calling `startActivity`, but it causes the same activity to be reloaded every time and can't let perform ui operation.

I have also tried `onResume` `onWindowAttached` methods but I could not figure out what to do there to reload activity. So I just called `setContentView` but it did not update the UI properly (Sometimes the locale is not applied and reset to default english or sometimes the wrong color is applied in background.)

There was no crash, no exception thrown.

I need your help to accomplish this task

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just update the Ui components and not the entire activity on `onItemSelected`.

Comment: yes. Either that or persist the value selected from the spinner and reload the activity using startActivity, and the use the persisted value to re-draw the UI

Comment: sorry dear, startActivity doesn't work and there are too many components to reload. So I m not considering your option seriously.

Comment: move the code you use to create ui components into a a separate method (lets call it setupUI) and pass the spinner value as an argument. The first time pass some default value and subsequently call setupUI from your `onItemSelected` method